# Is there a way to hide the navigation bar controller but not the status bar in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason, I want to hide the navigation bar but not the status bar(the signal, time, battery). When I use

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

This hides the navigation bar but also hides the status bar. Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: check the status bar setting in plist file

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to hide navigation bar:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

And use this code to unhide status bar:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

And check your plist file if `View controller-based status bar appearance` is set to NO then change it with YES as shown in below image:

[image]